# How to make permanent URL to S3 file in Obj C

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services

I am using aws s3 for storing files and returning links to those files. It's very convenient but I only know how to generate a pre-signed URL which only lasts for a set amount of time.

Is there anyway to generate a default URL which lasts permanently? I need the user to be able to access the photo from within their app. They take a photo, it's uploaded. They view it. Pretty standard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Handlers (DOI, PURL, PURLZ, persistant URIs)
All are free of charge, except for DOIs.
You create that handler, then you add it to your project.